# Problem in installing vscode

Tags: 23.04, visual-studio-code

i just installed Ubuntu 23.04, installed vs code from snap and official way.
but when i open vs code, that just frizzed and not working, when i use code --verbose there is a lot of error about everything.
thanks

Comment: Did you install using sudo snap install --classic code?

Comment: if did and nothing changes

Comment: 24.03 is not an Ubuntu release. Perhaps you mean 23.04? I'm speculating but you should edit your post to contain accurate information.

Comment: oh, thanks, edited

Comment: Did you try the deb package? https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/?dv=linux64_deb

Comment: i did, again that didn't work